# RxSwift, use .scan to keep track of the state of an object

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I know state is the enemy of Reactive programming but I'm dealing with it in my process of learning RxSwift.

My app is very simple, the first screen is a list and a search of books and the second a detail of the book in which you can **add/remove** a book to your shelf and mark it as **read/unread**.

To show the detail of the book I create a `BookViewModel` passing a `BooksService` to perform network operations and the current `Book` to show.

The problem is that I have to keep track of the changes in the book in order to change the UI: for example, after removing the book the button that previously says "Remove" now it has to say "Add".

I achieve this behavior using a `Variable<Book>` exposed to the observers as a `Driver<Book>`, but I'm messing a lot with it when the network operation returns and I have to update the value of the `Variable<Book>` in order to trigger the update of the UI.

This is the initializer of the view model:

```
init(book: Book, booksService: BooksService) {
    self._book = Variable(book)
    self.booksService = booksService
}
```

This is the observable I expose

```
var book: Driver<Book> {
    return _book.asDriver()
}
```

And here it is my function to add/remove the book:

```
func set(toggleInShelfTrigger: Observable<Void>) {
    toggleInShelfTrigger // An observable from a UIBarButtonItem tap
        .map({ self._book.value }) // I have to map the variable's value to the actual book
        .flatMap({ [booksService] book -> Observable<Book> in
            return (book.isInShelf ?
                    booksService.delete(book: book) :
                    booksService.add(book: book))
        }) // Here I have to know if the books is in the shelf or not in order to perform one operation or another.
        .subscribe(onNext: { self._book.value = $0 }) // I have to update the variable's value in order to trigger the UI update
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I am very unhappy with this code and the whole view model. It works but it is clunky, and essentially wrong because if the network operation fails the subscription will be disposed and my button will became unresponsive.

If I get rid of the `Variable<Book>` and return a `Driver<Book>` from the method `set(toggleInShelfTrigger: Observable<Void>)` I won't have this mess but I will not be able to know if I have to add or to remove the book.

So, what is the **real world** way to keep track of the state of an object in this kind of app? How can I achieve this by only using Rx operators?

## EDIT

I've managed to clean that crappy code but I'm still trying to achieve state without `Variable` and using `scan` operator.

This is my new `BookViewModel` initializer:

```
init(book: Book, booksService: BooksService) {
    self.bookVariable = Variable(book)
    
    let addResult = addBook
        .mapBookFrom(bookVariable)
        .flatMapLatest({ booksService.add(book: $0) })
        .updateBookVariable(bookVariable)

    let removeResult = ... // Similar to addResult, changing service call
    let markReadResult = ... // Similar to addResult, changing service call
    let markUnreadResult = ... // Similar to addResult, changing service call
    
    self.book = Observable.of(addResult, removeResult, markReadResult, markUnreadResult).merge()
        .startWith(.success(book))
}
```

I made a couple of custom operators to help me manage the `Variable<Book>`, one to get the real `Book`:

```
private extension ObservableType where E == Void {
    func mapBookFrom(_ variable: Variable<Book>) -> Observable<Book> {
        return map({ _ in return variable.value })
    }
}
```

And another to update the `Variable` after the service returns:

```
private extension ObservableType where E == BookResult<Book> {
    func updateBookVariable(_ variable: Variable<Book>) -> Observable<BookResult<Book>> {
        return self.do(onNext: { result in
            if case let .success(book) = result {
                variable.value = book
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now I have a very clean view model, but not "perfect".

Answer (score 1):

I would place the responsibility of the observing changes to the model object (Book) with the View.

Also, `Variable` is deprecated, best to use `PublishRelay` instead.

Of course, it depends how far you want to engineer this architecture, but something not too far from your example would be:

```swift
class BookDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    let viewModel = BookViewModel(book: Book, booksService: BooksService)

    func loadView() {
        view = BookDetailView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }

    // ...
}

class BookDetailViewModel {
    let book: PublishRelay<Book>

    func addBook() {
        book
            .flatMap(booksService.add)
            .bind(to: book)
            .subscribe()
    }

    // ...
}

class BookDetailView: UIView {
    let button: UIButton

    init(viewModel: BookDetailViewModel) {
        viewModel.book
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: { book [button] in 
               button.setText(book.isSaved ? "Remove" : "Add")
            })

        button.rx.tap
            .map { _ in viewModel.book.isSaved }
            .subscribe(onNext: { 
                $0 ? viewModel.removeBook() : viewModel.addBook() 
            }) 
    }
}
```

You could also implement a `func toggle()` in the view model instead, and just forward the button tap to call that method. It might be more accurate, semantically, depending on your interpretation of business logic and the extent to which you want to gather all of it in the view model.

Also note the example code is missing dispose bags, but that's another topic.

Comment: Thanks, I like your approach! :D But I'll have the same problem in terms of state with the `PublishRelay` because it is a subject. I want to refactor this to use `.scan` operator instead of using any kind of backup var.

Comment: Alright, I understand. Perhaps you can elaborate further what benefit you would get from encapsulating your model object inside `scan`? I'm not sure this is what the operator was meant for.

Comment: It is all related with statelessness. As I am learning Rx, and Rx has a tight relation with functional paradigm, I prefer to get all the knowledge about this in this first steps. You can learn more about this watching this talk about Reactive State by Jake Wharton, it is very interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IKHxjkgop4